# Java generates json of different file size if runner from console (jar)

Tags: java, json, intellij-idea

I use intellij to read one xml and to build a json out of it. 
If I run the program from intellij, the generated json file is 2.098 KB.

But when I made jar out of it, and when I run the jar from the windows console with the command

> java -jar file.jar

, it reads the same xml but the generated json file is smaller. is 2.084 KB.

Why I experience this? how is possible that jar generates smaller file?

Comment: It really hard to guess what could be root cause if we don;t know how you process input XML and what kind of transformations are you doing (if any). Maybe line ending issue? can you use diff tool to see actual differences? (such as windiff as you are on windows)

Comment: @rkosegi notepad++ diff finds no differences. the files are equal but with different size. how is this possible?

Comment: The difference is probably in the line terminator. Are you running on Windows? If so, System.lineSeparator is probably set to "\r\n" from the Command Prompt and "\n" within IntelliJ.

Comment: Sounds like whitespace difference. Line ending? Can you check diff of hexdump?

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou  how can I check this? 
how can i check the line separator? or the hexdump?

Comment: Since you are using Notepad++, look at the status bar at the bottom of the Window. If will say "Unix (LF)" or "Windows (CR LF)"

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou well now when i look it better i see some differences. The file generated with jar (which is smaller) from the command line is ANSI, and the file generated from intellij which is bigger is UTF-8. Can this be the difference? BOTH ARE Windows (CR LF)

Comment: also the file generated with console has less lenght but more columns. the file generated with intellij has bigger lenght but less number of columns. 
Can this be also the difference? HOW IS THIS POSSIBLE?

Comment: You tell us, it's your code.

Comment: You are using the "default system encoding" to write the file. This encoding is highly dependent on the environment in which the application is run. You can change it by using a JVM command line option. But I would recommend that you specify the encoding explicitly when you create a FileWriter/OutputStream/whatever you use, for consistent results.

Comment: http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/03/use-the-utf-8-luke-file-encodings-in-intellij-idea/

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou after specifying explicitly the encoding, i obtained the satisfying result. both generated files are of the same size. this question can be closed.